# Meteor - adding new user, changes the logged in user

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am having a weird issue,
I created a form that adds new user to the database and it works fine.

The problem now is, if I am logged in with "Alex" account, and I added "Leonard" to the database, Leonard will be added successfully, and the logged in user will change from Alex to Leonard.

How do I prevent this change?

**UPDATE :**

Here is my code:

```
Template.addingUser.events({
    'submit #addUser': function (e, t) {

        e.preventDefault();

        Session.set('name', t.find('#name').value);
        Session.set('email', t.find('#email').value);
        Session.set('homeAddress', t.find('#homeAddress').value);
        Session.set('pass', t.find('#pass').value);


        Session.set('taxNo', t.find('#taxNo').value);


        let userId = Accounts.createUser({
            username: Session.get('name'),
            password: Session.get('pass'),
            email: Session.get('email'),
            profile: {
            homeAddress: Session.get('homeAddress'),
        }

        }, function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log('It worked...');
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 1.1**

I tried to use `Accounts.onCreateUser` function. The user is successfully added, but the current logged in user will be signed out, after the addition.

here is my code:

Client:

```
var options = {
            username: t.find('#name').value,
            password: t.find('#pass').value,
            email: t.find('#email').value,
            profile: {
                homeAddress: t.find('#homeAddress').value,
            }
        };
        Meteor.call('createUser', options);
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    employeeAddition: function(options){
        Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
            if (options.profile)
                user.profile = options.profile;
        });
        var userId = Accounts.createUser();
    },
});
```

How do I prevent the current user from logging out after new user is being added?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to add the new user.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I updated the question :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are invoking `Accounts.createUser()` on the *client* instead of the *server*.

From the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser)

> **On the client, this function logs in as the newly created user** on
>   successful completion. On the server, it returns the newly created
>   user id.

You need to add a server method in which you invoke `Accounts.createuser()`

Comment: I am implementing the solution now, will get back to you in a moment, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the name, email, homeAddress and pass to the Session.
If you are using the Session.get('name') to control your logged user, that explain why the logged user are been updated.

Try do not set there values to the Session. I don't see the point of that.

Hope that help.

Comment: yeah your right, I am modifying the code now, hope it will work, will update you in a moment. Thanks

Comment: the code looks better and way lesser, thanks. the problem still remains tho -_-

Answer (score 1):

`Accounts.createUser` will log user in automatically after sign up successful, and it seems to be there is no options provided by `Meteor` to turn it off. So you would need to call `createdUser` by yourself to prevent that:

```
Meteor.call('createUser', {
  username: Session.get('name'),
  password: Accounts._hashPassword(Session.get('pass')),
  email: Session.get('email'),  // you have to hash the password
  profile: {
    homeAddress: Session.get('homeAddress'),
  },
}, function(err, re) {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: thanks, I upvoted you, this solution helped not logging in the new user, but the current user will be logged out -_-

Answer (score 0):

Using `Accounts.onCreateUser` solved it for me

Client:

```
var options = {
            username: t.find('#name').value,
            password: t.find('#pass').value,
            email: t.find('#email').value,
            profile: {
                homeAddress: t.find('#homeAddress').value,

            }
        };

        Meteor.call('employeeAddition', options);
```

Then I passed options to the method in which I invoked `Accounts.createUser` and `Accounts.onCreateUser`. As it is mentions in their [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser).

> By default the profile option is added directly to the new user document. To override this behavior, use Accounts.onCreateUser.

Here is the code:

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    employeeAddition: function(options){

        Accounts.createUser(options);

        Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
            if (options.profile)
                user.profile = options.profile;
        });
    },
});
```